# Rename multiple files in multiple directories to the name of the directory plus 1

Tags: command-line, rename

I have been attempting to rename a bunch of files to their directories.

I have multiple directories with spaces and no spaces `/The Dark Tower`.

In it are multiple titles with file names with spaces and no spaces as well:

```
/The Dark Tower/TDT feature.mov
/The Dark Tower/Main Trailer.mov 
/The Dark Tower/Trailer_Sub
```

I need to change the files in these directories with the name of the folder adding a number to the end of the file name:

```
/The Dark Tower/TDT feature.mov   ->   /The Dark Tower/The Dark Tower1.mov

/The Dark Tower/Main Trailer.mov  ->   /The Dark Tower/The Dark Tower2.mov

/The Dark Tower/Trailer_Sub       ->   /The Dark Tower/The Dark Tower3.mov
```

I have been doing this manually, but I would rather be able to do this with one script for 100 of movie titles I have. I know it can be done, but my current attempts have not been successful.

Comment: Do you need the file to be ordered?

Comment: @cuonglm No, I just need unique file names. I wanted to name them to the directory, but since a directory could contain multiple files, I need a way to make the title different since the file type is the same.

Comment: Any directories/titles with more than 9 files in them?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, no more than 5

Answer (score 1):

### Renaming Files with Bashisms

There are certainly other ways to do this, but if you're looking for a pure Bash solution that doesn't rely on any utilities other than the shell itself, the following will work.

```
dir="The Dark Tower"
declare -i count=1
for file in "$dir"/*.mov; do
    mv "$file" "${dir}/${dir} ${count}.mov"
    count+=1
done
```

Comment: The Dark Tower is just one of the Directories of Several. It is a child of the current Parent directory I am in. There are multiple child directories in here. How can I do this with all of the directories from the parent?

Comment: @AustinPerez Instead of assigning *dir* as a fixed string, you can wrap the rest of the rename code in another loop like `for dir in *`, or a specific list of quoted subdirectories instead of a glob. You are only limited by your glob-fu and your imagination.